# Does Facebook use an HTML5 framework for its mobile apps?

Tags: facebook, html, mobile

The Facebook iOS app, Android app, and mobile website are all very similar making me think they are all build using the same HTML5 framework. I'm particularly interested in the UI of the menu button on the top left that when clicked slides the window to the right to reveal a menu. I've seen other apps that do this too so I'm thinking they might be using a common framework. I've looked into JQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch, but they don't have that menu UI. Does anyone know what they are using?

Comment: Did you try [Zepto](https://github.com/tegansnyder/CNN-Like-Swipe-From-Top-Menu-Zepto.js-Mobile-HTML5)?

Comment: Facebook iOS App is not html5. It used to be but they changed it to be native and Zuckerberg said they gambled on html5 solving everything but it didn't http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/23/3262782/facebook-for-ios-native-app I can't speak for the Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is no longer using HTML5. Here is a Sencha Touch plugin, this is the closest that is available right now for ST as far as I know:
[Slide Navigation Menu on Sencha Market](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/collapsible-slide-navigation-menu)

Comment: Why do you hate it, and would do you prefer instead?